# Use filter to mark sensitive data for mousestats

Tags: angularjs

I want to decorate some sensitive data with MouseStats comments.
Currently i'm doing it like that:

```
<td><!-- StartMouseStatsHide -->{{ $ctrl.payerName }}<!-- EndMouseStatsHide --></td>
```

but there are plenty of sensitive data in many places of interface, so i tried to use a filter to decorate the value

```
<td>{{ $ctrl.payerName|mousestats_hide }}</td>
```

Filter simply surrounds value with comments.
The problem is that in that way comments are being escaped to entities.

What do you suggest?
Is it possible to do it using filters?

Comment: you just want to add comment around sensitive data right ? I think we can do it using filter and regular regular expressions. have you written any code for filter so far ? we need to have some pattern to detect sensitive data

Comment: we don't need any regular expression. Sensitive data may have any format. The goal is to create a filter which will add HTML comments around given values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it using filters?

Yes it is possible to prepend/append a variable using angular filters.

> The problem is that in that way comments are being escaped to entities..

That is because you are directly interpolating the variable in scope with `{{ $ctrl.payerName }}`. It does not parse HTML tags and show the resultant string as is.

You need `ng-bind-html` directive to prevent the comments being escaped to entities, if you want to *add HTML comments around given values*.

So rather than doing

```
<td>{{ $ctrl.payerName|mousestats_hide }}</td>
```

You should do

```
<td ng-bind-html="$ctrl.payerName|mousestats_hide"></td>
```

Here's the [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PGjnFPrVJ3Ey1qNM5KbF?p=preview) which generates the following markup.
(I'm not much of a fan of `<table>` so just replaced `<td>` with a `<span>`)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <span>Payer Name is: </span>
    <span ng-bind-html="payerName |mousestats_hide" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- StartMouseStatsHide -->Jakub Filipczyk<!-- EndMouseStatsHide --> 
    </span>
</body>
```

Noticed the use of $sce service I injected in filter ?

It is to prevent [[$sce:unsafe] error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe)  that makes angular believe someone is attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Hope it helped!